# Windows 10 boot in iMac without BootCamp

Tags: bootcamp, windows, install

The (quite elderly) parents of a friend have an iMac since years, but having worked with Windows all their lives, they never really managed to get around with it. Being retired they don't have access to their professional computer and they are faced with the Mac. They thought about getting rid of it and buy themselves a PC instead. However, I suggested them to install Windows 10 (OS that they would anyway get if they buy new material) in their existing machine in order to spare some money. I had 4 GB of "leftover" RAM in a drawer that I added in the computer thus boosting the total to 8 GB.

First I installed Windows 10 in a VirtualBox on top of Mac OS (which worked very well), but I quickly realized that it will be complicated for them especially with the keyboard (I don't want to install a second Windows keyboard). With a bit of online search I noticed that although BootCamp refuses to install Windows 10 (restricting any installation to Windows 7 which is not supported by Microsoft anymore) I can install the OS without BootCamp. There are numerous tutorials online that show how to do it (so far I used [this one](http://fgimian.github.io/blog/2016/03/12/installing-windows-10-on-a-mac-without-bootcamp/) and [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/2fy3be/by_popular_demand_my_better_than_bootcamp_guide/)).

However, I faced some issues. Here is what I do (please note that I already have the BootCamp drivers, but at this stage they are not yet needed and the Windows 10 installation is on the same USB key I used to install Windows 10 in VirtualBox – see above):

- start the computer
- press alt key
- after chime select EFI boot
- Return
- Windows splash screen
- a little while later some points whirling below the Windows logo
- then I have to wait approximately 20 minutes it gets to the
  "Language, Time & Currency and Keyboard" settings
- click next
- "Install now" screen appears immediately
- click "Install now" button
- "Setup is starting" screen which lasts more than 20 minutes
- then "Windows activation" screen
- enter the activation key
- click next
- after another 10 minutes the licence terms appears
- check "I accept…"
- click on next
- immediately I get the "Type of installation I choose Custom install…"
  screen
- then immediately I get the "Where do you want to install Windows?"
  screen but with the hourglass pointer (wait another 20 minutes)
- finally the installation location screen appears with **only** a
  `Drive 0 Unallocated Space` (although under Mac OS X I divided the
  disk into 700GB and 300GB partitions)
- then as per this [web page](http://fgimian.github.io/blog/2016/03/12/installing-windows-10-on-a-mac-without-bootcamp/) I click on New allocate
- type 700000
- click on Apply
- and nothing else happens…

I cannot click on Next, it is greyed out, as are the rest of the options (such as Refresh, Load driver, Delete, etc.)

I therefore have 2 questions:

- is there a solution to accelerate the process, in other words not
  have to wait 20 minutes between almost each event? (I don't think it
  is a question of USB stick as I can see the access at the beginning
  of each step, and then there seems to be no access as the led is not
  flashing, at all)
- even though the process is slow, if it is not solvable, it is not a
  big issue as the installation is supposed to be run only once, but at
  least get past the drive selection "challenge"?

Additional information:

- computer is a Late 2009 iMac
- Intel Core 2 Duo @ 3.06 GHz
- 8 GB RAM 1067 MHz DDR3
- Graphics card: ATI Radeon HD 4670 (256 MB)
- I already tried reseting the [PRAM/NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) and [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)

Thanks a lot in advance for any advice/help.

Comment: idk the answer to your allocation issue, however, if you do eventually get Win10 on there, there will be no drivers for hardware that old. That's one reason that Boot Camp restricts what OS you can install on which machine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Tetsujin, but I thought that [Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5722](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1836?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) was for newer models and Download [Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5769](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1837?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) was for older material (like the one I'm trying to install).

Comment: "This download contains the Windows Support Software (Windows Drivers) you need to support 64 bit versions of Windows 7 and Windows 8, and Windows 8.1 on your Mac." No drivers for WIn10 [& none for 32-bit either] - that's the sticking point, there are no Win10 drivers for that machine. Boot Camp 6 is for Win10 & can't be run on that Mac.